# Chrome cannot recognize HTML form submit button (<input type="submit" />)

Tags: html

ere is my code (including css):

```
        <form id="contactform" action="#" method="post">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="fieldbox" name="name" id="name" value=""/>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="fieldbox" name="email" id="email" value=""/>
            <label for="msg">Message</label>
            <textarea class="area fieldbox" id="msg" name="msg" rows="8" cols="20"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Send Message" id="sendbutton" name="sendbutton"/>
        </form>

#sendbutton {
background:top left no-repeat url(../images/send-button.jpg); 
color:#000;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
text-transform:uppercase;
padding:14px 57px 14px 13px;
float:right;
margin:10px 5px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;}
```

I have tested this code in Firefox, IE, and Chrome. Firefox and IE display the submit button as intended. Although Chrome displays the button, I cannot click it. It appears only as text. How can I fix this?

Note: Sorry for the poor code formatting. I am new here and I couldn't figure out how to format the code properly.

Update: I have identified the problem and fixed it. Changed from `float:right;` to `position:relative` and that did the trick.

Comment: try removing parts of the form until you are left with the exact minimum which will replicate the problem. then either show us the code that's left, or fix the bug that becomes obvious

Comment: I can't reproduce your symptoms in my copy of Chrome. The problem likely lies in some code you aren't sharing (e.g. JavaScript, CSS or some other bit of HTML).

Comment: Your `label` elements are useless, BTW, the `for` attribute refers to the `id` of the associated form control, and your controls don't have ids.

Comment: I have fixed the problem. Instead of floating the `#sendbutton`, I set the `position` to `relative` and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't see any issue. I added one line of php code in front of your code, and I was able to see all what I entered on the trip back:

```
 <?php
 echo var_export($_POST); 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran it through Chrome... works fine

I ran it through IE... works fine

Is there something on your machine that is preventing the button from being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 52.0.274 was showing my  as an input text box instead of a submit button until I modified the "DOCTYPE" from HTML 4 version (DTD...) to HTML 5 version . Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Add a name attribute to the Form tag, it tells the browser how to communicate the form to the server?

Comment: No it doesn't. The name attribute on the form element is only used client side, the id attribute should be used instead, but neither will help with this problem.